# Convert a string from args array to a single variable int with own method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, ascii

I am trying to make a method that will do what the title says. I think I am already done but for some reason every time I try to call this method I get an error. I always get array out of bounds.
Can someone point out my mistakes in this?
I am always sending the number in the second place after java ClassName
For example if I type in java ClassName something 2568, I send args[1] to the method.

```
public static int shiftHarder ( String commandLineInput )
{
    ArrayList <Character> commandLineString = new ArrayList <Character>();
    int counter;
    int number = 0;
    int ascii [] = new int [commandLineString.size()];
    int digits [] = new int [commandLineString.size()];

    for ( counter = 0; counter < commandLineInput.length(); counter++ )
    {
        commandLineString.add ( commandLineInput.charAt( counter ) ); 
    }

    for ( counter = 0; counter < commandLineString.size(); counter++ )
    {
        ascii [counter] = (int) commandLineString.get (counter);
    }

    if ( ascii [0] == 45 || ascii [0] == 43 )
    {
        for ( counter = 0; counter < ascii.length - 1; counter++ )
        {
            digits [counter] = ascii [counter + 1] -48;
        }

        if ( ascii [0] == 45)
        {
            for ( counter = 0; counter < digits.length; counter++ )
            {
                number = number*10;
                number = number + digits [counter];
            }
            number = - number; 
        }
        else
        {
            for ( counter = 0; counter < digits.length; counter++ )
            {
                number = number*10;
                number = number + digits [counter];
            }
        }           
    }

    else
    {
        for ( counter = 0; counter < ascii.length; counter++ )
        {
            digits [counter] = ascii [counter] -48;
        }

            for ( counter = 0; counter < digits.length; counter++ )
            {
                number = number*10;
                number = number + digits [counter];
            }
    }

    return number;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Integer.parseInt(commandLineInput)?

Comment: I am trying to do it myself. Yeah I know it will super easy like that

Comment: First of all, print the String that you are passing to that method, to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: If the input string is empty, ascii [0] would throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: It prints out as I want it so that is not the problem. I get out of bounds 0 if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the arrays to size zero since `commandLineString` is empty at that point:

```
int ascii [] = new int [commandLineString.size()];
int digits [] = new int [commandLineString.size()];
```

You probably meant

```
int ascii[] = new int[commandLineInput.length()];
int digits[] = new int[commandLineInput.length()];
```

Or else move the declaration of `ascii[]` and `digits[]` to after you've populated the `commandLineString` list